# Not + nth child в css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
    input[type=number]:not(#sun):nth-child(odd) {
        margin-right: 1px;
    }
```

Исключение срабатывает, но и nth-child его считает. Возможно ли сделать сделать так, чтобы nth-child пропускал этот элемент? Желательно средствами css.

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос. Непонятно, что вам нужно. Свойство применяется ко всем нечетным елементам, кроме елемента с `#sun`. Добавьте ваш `html`

Comment: Добавьте ваш html +

Comment: Тяжело понять без разметки, но если все же я правильно понял, то каждое исключение нужно указать отдельно: input[type=number]:not(#sun):not(:nth-child(odd))